# Delete all elements between two elements

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have about 2500 html-files of different standards. I need to remove the footer part of them. The HTML-code below is one of my files footer, and I need to remove the two hr-elements and the elements between the two.

So far I have only tried targeting the hr-element with xpath (and HTML Agility Pack) `selectSingleNode` and `DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//hr");`. And then try to iterate with a foreach.
But I am too much of a noob to use XPath properly, and don't know how to select the node and its siblings(?) to delete them.

This is what I've got so far, with the help of this community. :)

```
private static void RemoveHR(IEnumerable<string> files)
{
    var document = new HtmlDocument();
    List<string> hr = new List<string>();
    List<string> errors = new List<string>();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        try
        {
            document.Load(@file);
            i++;
            var hrs = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//hr");
            foreach (var hr in hrs) hr.Remove();
            document.Save(@file);

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            errors.Add(file + "|" + Ex.Message);
        }
    }
    using (StreamWriter logger = File.CreateText(@"D:\websites\dev.openjournal.tld\public\arkivet\ErrorLogs\hr_error_log.txt"))
    {
        foreach (var file in errors)
        {
            logger.WriteLine(file);
        }
    }
    int nrOfHr = hr.Count();
    int nrOfErrors = errors.Count();
    Console.WriteLine("Number of hr elements collected: {0}", nrOfHr);
    Console.WriteLine("Number of files missing hr element: {0}", nrOfErrors);
}
```

HTML-source:

```
<hr color=#ff00ff SIZE=3> //start element
<p style="text-align : center; color : Red; font-weight : bold;">How to cite this paper:</i></p>
<p style="text-align : left; color : black;">Ekmek&ccedil;ioglu, F. &Ccedil;una, Lynch, Michael F. &amp; Willett, Peter   (1996)&nbsp; &quot;Stemming and N-gram matching for term conflation in Turkish texts&quot;&nbsp;<em>Information Research</em>, <strong>1</strong>(1) Available at: http://informationr.net/ir/2-2/paper13.html</p>
<p style="text-align : center">&copy; the authors, 1996.</p>
<hr color="#ff00ff" size="1"><div align="center">Check for citations, <a href="http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&amp;q=http://informationr.net/ir/2-2/paper13.html&amp;btnG=Search&amp;as_sdt=2000">using Google Scholar</a></div>
                                 <hr color="#ff00ff" size="1">
<table border="0" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0" align="center">
<tr> 
    <td><a href="infres22.html"><h4>Contents</h4></a></td>
    <td align="center" valign="top"><h5 align="center"><IMG SRC="http://counter.digits.net/wc/-d/-z/6/-b/FF0033/paper13" ALIGN=middle  WIDTH=60 HEIGHT=20 BORDER=0 HSPACE=4 VSPACE=2><br><a href="http://www.digits.net/ ">Web Counter</a><br>Counting only since 13 December 2002</h5></td>
    <td><a href="http://InformationR.net/ir/"><h4>Home</h4></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<hr color=#ff00ff SIZE=3> //end element
```

EDIT
I experimented a bit with preceding-sibling and following-sibling to target nodes. Unfortunately it does not include the targeted nodes in the list.

```
var footerTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[preceding-sibling::p[contains(text(),'How to cite this')] and following-sibling::hr[@color = '#ff00ff']]");
```

It finds the paragraph with the text "How to cite this", then selects all node between it and down to the hr with color "ff00ff". But does not include the actual selected nodes in list to remove, and they need to be removed along with the selected nodes.

Comment: So, what happens when you run the code above? Do you get errors? Does it not delete the nodes?

Comment: Have you considered using regex instead? You might be able to create a pattern that matches the end of the file.

Comment: @ryan-wilson Yes it does, but as stated I need some help to delete everything between the two nodes. Unfortunately the two node look the same and I don't know how to use XPath properly.

Sidenote, when pasting code here, how do I format it properly? Any guides?

Comment: There is a `<hr />` node between the _start_ and _end_ elements. So does that mean the _start_ and _end_ elements **must** have the same `color` and `size` attribute values?

Comment: That's the problem, the start and end `<hr>`-node look the same, but I want to remove them as well. I did have some success with my SelectNodes-code above, but it does not remove the actual nodes it selects. 

I want to remove everything between the start and end nodes, including start and end. Not sure it is possible, maybe I need to divide it into separate methods for removal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the *start* and *end* nodes are ***truly the same*** (same tag name, attributes, and attribute values) as you mentioned in the comments above, it's not too hard:

1. Select the start node.
2. Iterate over and remove each sibling up to and including the end node.
3. Remove the start node.

Sample HTML:

```
var html =
@"<!doctype html system 'html.dtd'>
<html><head></head>
<body>

<div>DO NOT DELETE</div>

<hr color=""#ff00ff"" SIZE='3'> //start element
<p style='text-align : center; color : Red; font-weight : bold;'>How to cite this paper:</i></p>
<p style='text-align : left; color : black;'>Ekmek&ccedil;ioglu, F. &Ccedil;una, Lynch, Michael F. &amp; Willett, Peter   (1996)&nbsp; &quot;Stemming and N-gram matching for term conflation in Turkish texts&quot;&nbsp;<em>Information Research</em>, <strong>1</strong>(1) Available at: http://informationr.net/ir/2-2/paper13.html</p>
<p style='text-align : center'>&copy; the authors, 1996.</p>
<hr color='#ff00ff' size='1'><div align='center'>Check for citations, <a href='http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&amp;q=http://informationr.net/ir/2-2/paper13.html&amp;btnG=Search&amp;as_sdt=2000'>using Google Scholar</a></div>
                                 <hr color='#ff00ff' size='1'>
<table border='0' cellpadding='15' cellspacing='0' align='center'>
<tr> 
    <td><a href='infres22.html'><h4>Contents</h4></a></td>
    <td align='center' valign='top'><h5 align='center'><IMG SRC='http://counter.digits.net/wc/-d/-z/6/-b/FF0033/paper13' ALIGN=middle  WIDTH=60 HEIGHT=20 BORDER=0 HSPACE=4 VSPACE=2><br><a href='http://www.digits.net/'>Web Counter</a><br>Counting only since 13 December 2002</h5></td>
    <td><a href='http://InformationR.net/ir/'><h4>Home</h4></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<hr COLOR='#ff00ff' SIZE=""3""> //end element

<div>DO NOT DELETE</div>
</body>
</html>";
```

Parse it:

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);
var startNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//hr[@size='3'][@color='#ff00ff']");
// account for mismatched quotes in HTML source
var quotesRegex = new Regex("[\"']");
var startNodeNoQuotes = quotesRegex.Replace(startNode.OuterHtml, "");
HtmlNode siblingNode;

while ( (siblingNode = startNode.NextSibling) != null)
{
    siblingNode.Remove();
    if (quotesRegex.Replace(siblingNode.OuterHtml, "") == startNodeNoQuotes)
    {
        break;  // end node
    }
}

startNode.Remove();
```

Resulting output:

```
<!doctype html system 'html.dtd'>
<html><head></head>
<body>

<div>DO NOT DELETE</div>

 //end element

<div>DO NOT DELETE</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works great, I do have to alter it along the way. These hr-elements seem tricky in my documents. The original author used old standards and have not been super persistent. But your code identifies the hr with these exact attributes, and removes stuff between them. 

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think, you expect this ,

**Code**

```
string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\New Text Document.txt");
string html = Regex.Replace(content, "<hr.*?>", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

**Result**

```
//start element
<p style="text-align : center; color : Red; font-weight : bold;">How to cite this paper:</i></p>
<p style="text-align : left; color : black;">Ekmek&ccedil;ioglu, F. &Ccedil;una, Lynch, Michael F. &amp; Willett, Peter   (1996)&nbsp; &quot;Stemming and N-gram matching for term conflation in Turkish texts&quot;&nbsp;<em>Information Research</em>, <strong>1</strong>(1) Available at: http://informationr.net/ir/2-2/paper13.html</p>
<p style="text-align : center">&copy; the authors, 1996.</p>
<div align="center">Check for citations, <a href="http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&amp;q=http://informationr.net/ir/2-2/paper13.html&amp;btnG=Search&amp;as_sdt=2000">using Google Scholar</a></div>

<table border="0" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0" align="center">
<tr> 
    <td><a href="infres22.html"><h4>Contents</h4></a></td>
    <td align="center" valign="top"><h5 align="center"><IMG SRC="http://counter.digits.net/wc/-d/-z/6/-b/FF0033/paper13" ALIGN=middle  WIDTH=60 HEIGHT=20 BORDER=0 HSPACE=4 VSPACE=2><br><a href="http://www.digits.net/ ">Web Counter</a><br>Counting only since 13 December 2002</h5></td>
    <td><a href="http://InformationR.net/ir/"><h4>Home</h4></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
 //end element
```

Comment: Yes, and no. Yes I want to remove the hr-elements, but I also want to remove all the elements between theses two. So, all the html-elements between start and end element. The document contains more things (not listed here), and I don't want to remove any of the other elements by mistake. So your solution would remove stuff that must remain in document.

Comment: //start element and  //end element inside text are need clear in the document correct?

Comment: //start element and //end element are just comments to clarify where start and end is in this example. These comment-texts do not exist in original documents. Start and end element is of same type, ´<hr color=#ff00ff SIZE=3>´