# Break out an html-element from within a table-element

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm having problems finding a proper way of breaking out the H4-tag from the following code. Not only do I need to make it stay in the code, but I also need to delete the table it currently sits in.

So, how do I delete the whole table and keep the h4-tag where it is?

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td height="30" align="center" colspan="5"><h4>IMPORTANT HEADLINE ABOUT THIS PARTICULAR PAGE</h4></td></tr>
  <tr> 
    <td><a href="index.html" target="_top" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','group1','contents','',1)" onmouseover="MM_nbGroup('over','contents','../figs/contents1.gif','',1)" onmouseout="MM_nbGroup('out')"><img name="contents" src="../figs/contents.gif" border="0" alt="" onload=""></a></td>
    <td><a href="../page.html" target="_top" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','group1','authorindex','',1)" onmouseover="MM_nbGroup('over','authorindex','../figs/iauthori1.gif','',1)" onmouseout="MM_nbGroup('out')"><img src="../figs/iauthori.gif" alt="" name="authorindex" width="120" height="20" border="0" onload=""></a></td>
    <td><a href="../page.html" target="_top" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','group1','subjindex','',1)" onmouseover="MM_nbGroup('over','subjindex','../figs/isubji1.gif','',1)" onmouseout="MM_nbGroup('out')"><img src="../figs/isubji.gif" alt="" name="subjindex" width="120" height="20" border="0" onload=""></a></td>
    <td><a href="../search.html" target="_top" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','group1','search','',1)" onmouseover="MM_nbGroup('over','search','../figs/isearch1.gif','',1)" onmouseout="MM_nbGroup('out')"><img src="../figs/isearch.gif" alt="" name="search" width="120" height="20" border="0" onload=""></a></td>
    <td><a href="../page.html" target="_top" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','group1','home','',1)" onmouseover="MM_nbGroup('over','home','../figs/ihome1.gif','',1)" onmouseout="MM_nbGroup('out')"><img name="home" src="../figs/ihome.gif" border="0" alt="" onload=""></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Further on I have about 2500 html-documents following similar structure, but are in different versions of HTML, thus uses div's, tables or other elements from version to version. So I need a way to alter this method properly.

I have a document load ready, it loads all files in a list, so I will be feeding a method this list of filenames to open and parse. But I can't figure out how to use XPath for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve the problem is to find all `<h4>` nodes, walk up it's parent chain until you find a *stop* tag/node, and replace the *stop* tag/node with your `<h4>`:

Given some sample HTML that resides in a **HTML file**:

```
var html =
@"<!doctype html system 'html.dtd'>
<html><head></head>
<body>
<table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<tr><td height='30' align='center' colspan='5'><h4>IMPORTANT HEADLINE ABOUT THIS PARTICULAR PAGE</h4></td></tr>
  <tr> 
    <td><a href='index.html'><img name='contents' src='../figs/contents.gif' border='0' alt='' onload=''></a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.html'><img src='../figs/iauthori.gif' alt='' name='authorindex' width='120' height='20' border='0' onload=''></a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.html'><img src='../figs/isubji.gif' alt='' name='subjindex' width='120' height='20' border='0' onload=''></a></td>
    <td><a href='../search.html'><img src='../figs/isearch.gif' alt='' name='search' width='120' height='20' border='0' onload=''></a></td>
    <td><a href='../page.html'><img name='home' src='../figs/ihome.gif' border='0' alt='' onload=''></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div>
<h4>H4 nested in DIV</h4>
<p>Paragraph <strong>bold</strong> <a href=''>Hyperlink</a></p>
</div>

<p><h4>H4 nested in P</h4></p>

</body>
</html>";
```

Parse it with this method:

```
public string ParseHtmlToString(string inputFilePath)
{
    var document = new HtmlDocument();
    document.Load(inputFilePath);
    var wantedNodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h4");
    // stop at these tags while walking backwards up the chain
    var stopTags = new string[] { "table", "div", "p" };
    HtmlNode parentNode;

    foreach (var node in wantedNodes)
    {
        HtmlNode testNode = node;
        while ((parentNode = testNode.ParentNode) != null)
        {
            if (stopTags.Contains(parentNode.Name))
            {
                parentNode.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(node, parentNode);
            }
            testNode = parentNode;
        }
    }

    return document.DocumentNode.WriteTo();
}
```

Then you can assign the parsed HTML to a variable like this:

```
var parsedHtml = ParseHtmlToString(INPUT_FILE);
```

which returns the following value:

```
<!doctype html system 'html.dtd'>
<html><head></head>
<body>
<h4>IMPORTANT HEADLINE ABOUT THIS PARTICULAR PAGE</h4>

<h4>H4 nested in DIV</h4>

<h4>H4 nested in P</h4>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanx for the code! However, I want to keep the rest of the code in the document. Meaning I only want to remove the table that surrounds the one h4 that have the important headline for the document. 

I haven't tested your thing yet..but I am sure it does what you said. But as I understand it, I can have table as my stoptag and only remove h4 within it? The problem is that I have other "tables" in these documents that hold research data, which needs to be kept intact.

Comment: Would you mind also having a look at my other problem related to this, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48891744/delete-all-elements-between-two-elements/48892408

Comment: @ChristerJohansson - yes, the code will **only** remove `<table>`'s that have `<h4>`. All other `<table>`'s are untouched.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I can't get my head around this. On the first run (In the foreach-loop) it prints out the H4-tag, second run also, but on 3 and 4 run it prints out the original html unedited, kind of restoring it back. 

Would you mind clarifying how I would implement your solution in a basic method where I save the edited data into a variable? I will save it into the original file within the foreach-loop when the loop is done.

Comment: Not sure why the code isn't working for you, unless your HTML files contain different markup from your example. The answer has been tested and working. Anyway, updated the answer to reflect your comment above: include a simple method that accepts a **full file path** to a HTML file, parses it, and returns a `string`  so you can assign the edited HTML to a variable.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to test it tomorrow again. I am sure its my own shortcomings as a junior dev that causes the issues. I'll mark your answer as the correct one. Very grateful for all your help! :)

Comment: @ChristerJohansson - No worries. The only other suggestion is to run in debug mode and set breakpoints as needed so you can step through line(s) of code and see exactly what's going on at runtime. I understand that the code you provided is only a small part of your actual code (as it should be in a good SO question), and there are many other things you're doing. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a alternative solution, it worked for all those documents where the Kuujinbo-solution failed, I ran them side by side as a try/final/catch-method. And it worked pretty good through all 2500 html-docs.

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(file);
var htmlBody = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
var headerTables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body/table[1]");
var headerNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//h4[contains(text(),'Information Research, Vol')]");
htmlBody.ReplaceChild(headerNode, headerTables);
headerTables.Remove();
doc.Save(file);
```

Basically it was run as

```
try {ParseHtmlToString(file)}
final {myAlternateSolution(file)}
catch (Exception Ex){Console.WriteLine(file +":"+ Ex.Message);}
```

It worked due to the fact that the table was most of the time the first node after body, and it was also the first table in the document. Some manual editing had to be done, due to the fact that some documents had malformed HTML, and could not be repaired with HTMLTidy and similar.